# Cyclic image view in fancybox plugin for jQuery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

my **fancybox** code looks like this:

```
$.fancybox([
    {"href":"image1.jpg"},
    {"href":"image2.jpg"},
    {"href":"image3.jpg"}
     ]);
```

when adding parameter `"cyclic":true` it fails:

```
$.fancybox([
    {"href":"image1.jpg"},
    {"href":"image2.jpg"},
    {"href":"image3.jpg"},
    {"cyclic":true}
]);
```

what's the matter?

Comment: Can you define `it fails`? Do you get an error? Also, in your first example, you have an extra `}`

Comment: @Rory McCrossan  extra ``}`` is just a mistake, no i don't get an error, but instead of cycling i get one empty photo..

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use the new version http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ ?
The cyclic is called loop

> **loop** - If set to true, enables cyclic navigation. This means, if you click "next" after you reach the last element, first element will be displayed (and vice versa).